# Angular - Default option of select not showing in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a drpdown list. In my html I have this:

```
    <select id="universitySel" ng-model="universityValue" ng-options="university._id for university in universities">
        <option value="-1">Choose university</option>
    </select>
```

I bind this dropdown from my collection. I want to show optional text as first element as you see above. First element is always empty. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the `value` to an empty string `""`:

```
<option value="">Choose university</option>
```

(from Angular's [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions):)

> Optionally, a single hard-coded `<option>` element, with the value set to an **empty string**, can be nested into the  element. This element will then represent the null or "not selected" option.

Comment: A single element, that should be remarked. I was trying  to add two and then I found this answer. Thank you!

Comment: I intrusive is this? Angular is actually modifying the default html select behavior, for what? To cause headaches?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="universitySel" ng-model="universityValue" ng-options="university._id for university in universities">
    <option value="" disabled>--Select your University--</option>
</select>
```

This will make your code look perfect.